# How to work with millions of files when xargs does not work

Tags: filter, filesystems, xargs

In some cluster I need to enter in some directory and list and select some files. The problem is that probably there are even millions of very small files. If I do

```
ls -l
```

It is very inefficient. But if I try a supposed to be better alternative like

```
find . -name "*.mol2" | xargs ls
```

It takes minutes and I do not get any answer ...

I wonder if there are better/faster methods for situations like this one. Of course I could tell the person who generated all these files something, but this is out of the scope of the question. Thanks

Comment: The problem here is likely searching through the filesystem index for so many files, whether using ls or find. Given the situation, find is your best choice, but don't bother with xargs, output your filenames to another file to "cache" those hits so you can run commands against the list later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious would be:

```
find . -name "*.mol2"
```

But with millions of files it will still take time - at least the first time. The second time the dir will hopefully be cached.

For the outside scope: Create subdirs maybe named as substrings, so foobarbaz123.mpl2 will go into foo/bar/baz/foobarbaz123.mpl2

Answer (score 0):

How about `ls -al *.mol2 .*mol2`?